# Accessing v3 endpoints using apikey in surveymonkey

Tags: api, surveymonkey

As I am upgrading my app to use v3 apis, I am doing that using old api key registered before v3 apis. Will that work or do I need to generate new api key?

Currently after successfully getting the oauth token, when I try to read surveys list, I always get the value of X-OAuth-Scopes-Granted as None in response Header. The doc says that users need to grant the scope but I am not able to find the setting in my survey monkey account that I can use to grant view scopes(survey_read) to my app. I am using Free account plan. Am I missing something?

While accessing https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys, I am getting below message

{"error": {"docs": "https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#error-codes", "message": "The following scopes have not been granted: View your surveys and those shared with you", "id": "1014", "name": "Permission Error", "http_status_code": 403}}

Answer (score 1):

You can continue to use your current credentials (API key, client ID and secret), though we do suggest creating a new app or refreshing your credentials when migrating to V3, as it removes the need for an API key.

You can define the scopes your app needs by enabling them on the settings page for your app. Go to https://developer.surveymonkey.com/apps/ and click "Settings" for you app.

Scopes are further defined here: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#scopes